# How to convert a list to a one dimensional array (vector) in Common Lisp having the same output either using make-array or coerce?

Tags: arrays, list, vector, common-lisp

I want to convert from a simple list:

```lisp
'(1 2 3)
```

To a one dimensional array (vector):

```lisp
#(1 2 3)
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549568/common-lisp-convert-between-lists-and-arrays) which is similar but does not cover this problem.

I also managed to find a way to achieve it. Not sure if it is the best:

```lisp
CL-USER> (coerce '(1 2 3) 'vector)
#(1 2 3)
CL-USER> (type-of *)
(SIMPLE-VECTOR 3)
```

I wonder if it is possible to use `make-array` to achieve the same result. I tried:

```lisp
CL-USER> (make-array '() :initial-contents '(1 2 3)) 
#0A(1 2 3)
CL-USER> (type-of *)
(SIMPLE-ARRAY T NIL)
```

This is close, but I do not understand `#0A` in `#0A(1 2 3)`.

For some reason that I do not understand, this output does not work on further compositions, such as `aref`:

```lisp
CL-USER> (aref #0A(1 2 3) 0)
; Evaluation aborted on #<SIMPLE-ERROR "Wrong number of subscripts, ~W, for array of rank ~W." {1003C07793}>.
```

Is it possible to use `make-array` to achieve the same result as `coerce`?
What are the differences between these two approaches?
Is one of them faster or more elegant than the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`COERCE` is fine, you can even specify the element-type if you want:

```
USER> (coerce '(1 2 3) '(vector fixnum))
#(1 2 3)
USER> (describe *)
#(1 2 3)
  [simple specialized vector]

Element-type: FIXNUM
Length: 3
```

You can do the same with `make-array`, but you need to give the right dimension. The dimension parameter indicates how many rows, columns, etc. the possibly multi-dimensional array has. It should be a list, but when you only have one dimension, it can just be a number. Both forms here are equivalent:

```
USER> (make-array 3 :initial-contents '(1 2 3))
#(1 2 3)

USER> (make-array '(3) :initial-contents '(1 2 3))
#(1 2 3)
```

Usually you would call `(length list)`. The added value compared to `coerce` is that you can specify the `:fill-pointer` or `:adjustable` arguments, something that the type argument of `coerce` cannot convey.

The printed representation of an array is `#nA()`, where `n` is the number of dimensions of the array, where the number and `A` is omitted if its a vector (n = 1). For example:

```
USER> (make-array '(10 2) :initial-element 0)
#2A((0 0) (0 0) (0 0) (0 0) (0 0) (0 0) (0 0) (0 0) (0 0) (0 0))
```

For a given array of dimension `n`, you access the elements with `aref` and as many arguments as there are dimensions, in *row-major* order (the same order you specified the dimensions in `make-array`).

```
USER> (aref * 5 1)
0 (0 bits, #x0, #o0, #b0)
```

In your example, you defined an array of dimension 0, because you wrote `'()` (a.k.a. just `()` or `nil`) as the dimension. This can be used if you need a box to store a single element:

```
USER> (defparameter *box* (make-array nil :element-type '(mod 8)))
*BOX*
USER> (describe *box*)
#0A0
  [simple specialized array]

Element-type: (UNSIGNED-BYTE 4)
Dimensions: NIL
Storage vector: #<(SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 4) (1)) {101EA0C59F}>
; No values

USER> (setf (aref *box*) 7)
7 (3 bits, #x7, #o7, #b111)

USER> (incf (aref *box*))
8 (4 bits, #x8, #o10, #b1000)

USER> (aref *box*)
8 (4 bits, #x8, #o10, #b1000)
```

<sub>(as you can see, the values that can be stored in the array are the ones corresponding to the `upgraded-element-type`, here `(unsigned-byte 4)`; for example, `(setf (aref *box*) (expt 2 16))` signals an error)</sub>

It looks like `:initial-contents` had the same result as `:initial-element`, because with your example the content of the zero-dimensional array was the list `(1 2 3)`

> Is one of them faster or more elegant than the other?

I try to use `coerce` when possible because it's shorter to write and it looks more descriptive of what I am doing. I don't think it is faster, unless you know in advance the length of the list.